# Mock AmazonS3Client without any dependency like s3mock or s3ninja

Tags: java, amazon-s3, junit, mockito

A method in a class uses AmazonS3Client like below:

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                       .withCredentials(new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider())
                       .build();
```

followed by line

```
Response response=s3Client.someMethod(request)
```

AmazonS3ClientBuilder couldn't be mocked being final class.
Moreover, I just randomly tried @Mock for AmazonS3 and i just try mocking line as:

```
when(s3Client.someMethod(request)).thenReturn(response)
```

This resulted in

> Unable to load aws credentials for any providers in chain.

I guess this is because AmazonS3ClientBuilder is still active. When i checked for alternative, i came across s3mock,s3ninja but the repo i use for maven is private and doesn't contain it. So could you please suggest a way to solve this problem?

Comment: You could consider abstracting a way around it instead of tightly coupling to 3rd part dependency. That way is allows for separation of concerns. This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the end goal you are ultimately trying to achieve?

Comment: i was just writing a test class  on this and this test fails due to error mentioned.